# How to call external contract with abi.encodeWithSignature with no arguments?

Tags: solidity

I'm using solidity 0.5.16 and in a contract's function, I want to make a call to another contract's `initialize()` method. This method does not take in any arguments.

```
        contract.call.value(0)(
          abi.encodeWithSignature("initialize()",);
        );
```

However the above method does not compile properly..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Don't use the reserved keyword `contract` - replace it to `externalContract` for example.
2. When you're not passing any arguments, remove the comma sign `,` within the `encodeWithSignature()` function.
3. Remove the semicolon `;` after the `encodeWithSignature()`. This would cause another parse error because you're still building an argument within the `call` function.

```
pragma solidity 0.5.16;

contract MyContract {
    function foo() external {
        address externalContract = address(0x123);
        (bool success, bytes memory returnedData) = externalContract
            .call.value(0)(
                abi.encodeWithSignature("initialize()"
            )
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The above syntax is deprecated now, you can use this instead:

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract MyContract {
    function foo() external {
        address externalContract = address(0x123);
        (bool success, bytes memory returnedData) = externalContract.call
            {value: 0}
            (abi.encodeWithSignature("initialize()")
        );
    }
}
```